# My Honda Odessey loses power all of sudden while driving

Tags: honda, electrical, power, odyssey

My 2016 Honda Odyssey loses power all of a sudden while driving. Everything loses power. Radio gone, speedometer stuck at 38mph, frozen, same with tachometer. I could not open a door or a window. I called AAA.

One might suspect an Alternator, but the battery was still fully charged registering 12.75 volts. After 45 minutes I was able to open a door and wind down a window. Let AAA guy look at it and he thought it might be a rare computer failure. Battery terminals were tight, battery is less than 6 months old.

When I start the car afterwards and in 4-5 times since this incident it starts immediately. I kinda wonder if it is a processor chip problem. Some processors when their on board temp sensors reach a high temperature shut down. 45 minutes is the sort of time it might take for a chip to cool off.

I did take it to Honda and paid $175 for a full diagnosis. They looked for codes and found nothing. Took them 2 hours. They suggest I replace the battery, but I test the battery when stopped and when back from the dealer and the battery reads 12.75 volts and the car starts immediately.

When it lost power everything went immediately. There was no battery warning light as with an alternator. Everything went immediately. I was quite baffled that I couldn't even open any door or wind a window and it is bizarre that electrical seemed to come back in about 45 minutes, but I waited for AAA which I called soon after I was stopped.

At this point I don't think its an alternator or a battery.

I'd appreciate any further ideas. The two times this has happened have been safe as I was on streets without the need to change too many lanes and could safely coast to a stop.

I am starting it via the push button. I believe it is a 6 cylinder engine. The car has about 75,000 miles and has been serviced at dealers regularly The last service was only two weeks before the recent issues began. The big item there was replacing the timing belt.

Comment: Please state the year, trim and engine. Key start or pushbutton start? Side note: a dealer's service writer who suggests changing the battery when it reads 12.75 volts and without load testing the battery is not acting in your best interest, but in his own.

Comment: I would take the vehicle for a drive with the alternator electrical connector disconnected and see if it happens now. I am making the assumption since you had this to the dealership they would surely have checked for any TSB's.